# Wireshark "Save As" Greyed Out

Tags: wireshark

When I open the "File" menu in Wireshark, the "Save" and "Save As" entries are both greyed out, and clicking on them does nothing:

[image: Picture of inactive "Save As" menu entry]

I wish to save a subset of packets from a .cap file (which was exported from Microsoft Message Analyzer v1.4, which was originally captured by netsh).

I've tried:

- Running Wireshark as an admin (on Windows 7 Pro).
- Ensuring that I have ownership of the .cap file and the folder it resides in.

The [documentation](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChIOSaveSection.html) for the "Save As" feature does not mention under what situations the option is greyed out and unavailable.

Does anyone know what's going on?

---

Capture File Properties:

```
Created by Wireshark 2.6.5 (v2.6.5-0-gf766965a)

File

Name:
C:\Users\user\Downloads\NetTrace - Copy.cap
Length:
11 MB
Format:
Microsoft NetMon 2.x
Encapsulation:
Ethernet

Time

First packet:
2018-11-30 09:06:17
Last packet:
2018-11-30 09:19:04
Elapsed:
00:12:46

Capture

Hardware:
Unknown
OS:
Unknown
Application:
Unknown

Interfaces

Interface
Dropped packets
Capture filter
Link type
Packet size limit
Wireless Network Connection
Unknown
none
Ethernet
262144 bytes

Statistics

Measurement
Captured
Displayed
Marked
Packets
56200
191 (0.3%)
—
Time span, s
766.877
360.633
—
Average pps
73.3
0.5
—
Average packet size, B
178
346
—
Bytes
10015936
66086 (0.7%)
0
Average bytes/s
13 k
183
—
Average bits/s
104 k
1466
—
```

---

Wireshark Help > About:

```
Version 2.6.5 (v2.6.5-0-gf766965a)
Compiled (64-bit) with Qt 5.9.7, with WinPcap (4_1_3), with GLib 2.42.0, with zlib 1.2.11, with SMI 0.4.8, with c-ares 1.14.0, with Lua 5.2.4, with GnuTLS 3.4.11, with Gcrypt 1.7.6, with MIT Kerberos, with MaxMind DB resolver, with nghttp2 1.14.0, with LZ4, with Snappy, with libxml2 2.9.4, with QtMultimedia, with AirPcap, with SBC, with SpanDSP, with bcg729.
Running on 64-bit Windows 7 Service Pack 1, build 7601, with Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3320M CPU @ 2.60GHz (with SSE4.2), with 8065 MB of physical memory, with locale English_United States.1252, with WinPcap version 4.1.3 (packet.dll version 4.1.0.2980), based on libpcap version 1.0 branch 1_0_rel0b (20091008), with GnuTLS 3.4.11, with Gcrypt 1.7.6, without AirPcap, binary plugins supported (14 loaded). Built using Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 (VC++ 14.12, build 25835).
```

Comment: Try to stop the capturing session then save it.

Comment: The "Stop capturing packets" button is greyed out; I'm not capturing from an interface.  I'm viewing a file.

Comment: That option is visible in my PC. Did you change any settings recently? Close Wireshark > Rename this folder `"C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\Wireshark"` > open WireShark.

Comment: I closed Wireshark, renamed that folder, then launched Wireshark again.  I still have that issue.

Comment: I'm also running Wireshark 2.6.5 and I don't experience this problem when testing with a Netmon 2.x file from the Wireshark menagerie.  Maybe post your "Help -> About Wireshark" details?  In the meantime, you can use "File -> Export Specified Packets -> All packets" and choose your file name and file type that way instead of using "File -> Save As"; it should accomplish the same thing.

Comment: @ChristopherMaynard "File -> Export Specified Packets..." is also greyed out.  (See picture).

Comment: OK, I missed that.  Are you able to share the capture file somewhere so further analysis can be performed as to why this is happening?

Comment: See: https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/17547/microsoft-network-monitor-cap-file-can-be-opened-by-wireshark-but-save-as-function-is-disabled

Comment: It's *possible* that the very latest version of Wireshark supports what you need.  You could try installing one of the latest automated builds from https://www.wireshark.org/download/automated/.  If even that doesn't work, then you might consider opening up a Wireshark bug report at: https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/.  The Wireshark developers will probably want a sample capture file to test with though.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this from Wireshark itself.

Use the program [editcap](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/editcap.html),
which is a console program that is installed together with Wireshark.

For example, to get all packets from number 1-500 (inclusive) use:

```
editcap -r capture.pcap first500.pcap 1-500
```

Comment: When I try that, I get this error: `editcap: The capture file being read can't be written as a "pcapng" file.`

Comment: Try to open it in Wireshark and save it as pcap or pcapng.

Comment: How do you suggest I do that?  The title of my question is literally "wireshark save as greyed out".

Comment: OK. Try : `editcap -F pcap input.cap output.pcap` and also `tshark -F libpcap -w output.pcap -r input.cap`.